# What's the Fix for an iFrame Height Issues in FireFox?

Tags: html, css, firefox, iframe

I have looked around and gone through my code several times, but just can't find a solution to my issue:

The iFrame in FireFox:

[image: FireFox iFrame]

The iFrame in Chrome:

[image: Chrome iFrame]

HTML:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameBorder="0" id="map" src="link-to-map"></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
#map {
    max-width: 900px;
    height: 400px !important;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
```

Nothing I try fixes the height issue in FireFox, has anyone else had this problem and found a solution?

Comment: Why `height="100%"` and height in the css?

Comment: @ webnoob Because the iFrame is inside a container.

Comment: use min-height instead of height

Comment: In FireFox 23.0 and 24.0 it works, Probably you have this iframe within another div? http://jsfiddle.net/GG6Tb/

Comment: @ Bondye I have tried putting in http://maps.google.com and the iFrame works, however when I put in the source from http://www.mapbox.com/ the iFrame does not display the height correctly. Is there a fix with Javascript to fit the content inside the iframe to the iFrame height?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle, I have registered and created a mapbox and it is still working in Firefox 24

Comment: I've had a same issue with iframe inside div container. Fixed by `position: absolute;` in iframe class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the issue I was having was a `<span>` class with the property of `display:none;` (used for jQuery page loading), I changed this to a `<div>` with the property of `visibility: hidden;` and this has fixed the issue.

It seems to only be an issue in FireFox. I'm not sure if it's a bug or maybe just my poor coding.

Hopefully this saves someone else a lot of stress in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try placing the iframe at

```
height:100%;
```

in a div of

```
height: 400px !important;
```

or just make the iframe

```
height: 400px;
```

Answer (score 0):

`<iframe width="880px" height="380px" frameBorder="0" id="map" src="link-to-map"></iframe>`

```
#map {
max-width: 900px;
height: 400px !important;
padding: 10px;
margin: 20px auto;
```

}

Hope that'll work...